# What assumptions about time series data are neccessary to use a stateless LSTM?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, lstm

Basically I am trying to model a time series using an LSTM layer, and I was wondering whether I should be using a stateful or stateless LSTM layer. More specifically I was wondering what assumptions need to be true about my time series data (should it be covariance stationary?, Do stateless Keras LSTM Layers assume that each batch of the sequence is independent and identically distributed from the other batchs?) in order to have it best modeled by the stateful version of the LSTM, or the stateless version of the LSTM.